# Avoid code duplication with interface in golang

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I am using the Google Cloud Datastore (or the google app engine datastore), to store different objects. Most of these objects are similar, hence I end up with lots of code duplication.

As an example, here are two create methods, of two different objects, `account` and `index`.

```
func (account *Account) Create(ctx context.Context) (*Account, error) {
  if ret, err := datastore.Put(ctx, account.newKey(ctx), account); err != nil {
    log.Errorf(ctx, "Error while creating Account : %v\n", err)
    return nil, err
  } else {
    account.Id = strconv.FormatInt(ret.IntID(), 10)
  }

  return account, nil
}
```

---

```
func (index *Index) Create(ctx context.Context) (*Index, error) { 
  if ret, err := datastore.Put(ctx, index.newKey(ctx), index); err != nil {
    log.Errorf(ctx, "Error while creating Index : %v\n", err)
    return nil, err
  } else {
    index.Id = strconv.FormatInt(ret.IntID(), 10)
  }

  return index, nil
}
```

As you can see, the two snippets are identical, excepts for the holder type, the return type, and the error message.

**What is the idiomatic way to avoid this kind of code duplication ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use interface to define methods `NewKey()` & `SetID()`

```
type Entity interface {
  SetId(id int64)
  NewKey(c context.Context) *datastore.Key
}

func create(c context.Context, entity Entity) error { 
  if ret, err := datastore.Put(c, entity.NewKey(c), entity ); err != nil {
    log.Errorf(c, "Error while creating entity: %v\n", err)
    return err
  } else {
    entity.SetId(ret.IntID())
    return nil
  }
}

func (index *Index) Create(c context.Context) (*Index, error) {
  return index, create(c, index)
}

func (account *Account) Create(c context.Context) (*Account, error) {
  return account, create(c, account)
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it feels strange to have the function `create` not being a method. The reason is that I might have several kinds of entity. Identified ones, and unidentified ones for example. And I need to implement the `create` function differently for these different entities.
So I wanted to make it a method for each entity, but it ended up being a mess.
But I guess I will have to name these functions differently, like `createIdedEnt` and `createUnidedEnt`, instead of relying on methods.

Comment: I would decouple data access layer from entity.

like: AccountDal().Create(ctx, account).